# How to handle a POST request to a URL that contains route parameters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC4 web app, and I have a controller method for handling a `GET` request with an `id` in the URL, like so ...

```
[PortalAuthorization]
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    // get the individual ftp log
    PortalFTPLog log = PortalFTPLogs.Get(id);

    if (log == null)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "The provided ftp log id does not exist.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // get the available matters to tie uploads to
    ViewBag.matters = PortalMatters.Get();

    return View(log);
}
```

In my view for this controller method, I have a form so that they can update it, that I want to `POST` back to the same URL. A URL like `foo.com\items\1`. Thats what the function above handles.

How do I make a function that handles a `POST` request for a function that requires a parameter, though? IN previous `POST` handlers I create a FormsCollection param, but when I add it to the param list for this function, the `id` param is null.

```
[HttpPost]
[PortalAuthorization]
public ActionResult View(FormCollection collection, int id)
{
    PortalFTPLog log = PortalFTPLogs.Get(id);

    if (log == null)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "The provided ftp log id does not exist.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // update the matter id and save to database
    log.Matter = Convert.ToInt32(collection.Get("matter"));
    log.Save();

    TempData["Notice"] = "The FTP log meta data has been updated.";

    return RedirectToAction("View", new { id = id });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide RouteValues in Html.BeginForm on your View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new {id = someIntIdValue}))
 {
     // Your form code  
 }
```